# Host Injection Vulnerability Successful HTTP codes?

Tags: vulnerability, injection, html, header

I am trying to exploit Host Injection Vulnerability of a website.

If I change the host or add another host, what all are the HTTP response codes that will tell me about a successful HTML Host Injection Vulnerability?

I read a PoC (https://hackerone.com/reports/94637) of a HOST injection vulnerability where there was a `301 Moved Temporarily` response when he changed host using Burp Suite and he was awarded a bounty.

What are all the HTML codes for successful HOST injection?

```
200 OK
301 Moved Temporarily 
and ???
```

Comment: it's really going to depend on the server and application .... potentially any non-error could indicate success ...

Comment: It will be really helpful if u list all the html successful codes that will tell me about a successfull attack . i will accept the ans

Comment: You want me to list all HTTP success codes? There are sites that have that list. As I said above, how any one site responds will be up to that individual site.

Comment: I want u 2 list the cods for successful host header injection that's all

Comment: HTTP error codes are anything in 4xx or 5xx category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP error codes are anything in 4xx or 5xx category.  4xx means client error, 5xx means server error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes. As schroeder indicates, any code in 1xx, 2xx, or 3xx category that you receive potentially means success.